# What happened to this question when I edited it?

Tags: bug, edits, specific-edit, diff

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372221/how-to-save-output-of-my-loop-in-a-dataframe-r-studio) had a critical Markdown issue, where the post had an image and a code block, and the image link was accidentally included in the code block, causing the image not to render. I opened the editor, properly closed off the code block, and submitted it. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28892806

But the diff says I erased entire sentences and then added back my own words!

For instance, it says I **removed**:

> 'that has a column called "pp" with a lot of values',

and that I **added**:

> '(check the picture)'.

Was this really just a crazy accident with highlight and backspace on my end? Do I have amnesia? Or did something else happen?

I want to make sure I understand what happened because the information that I supposedly deleted seems important to include in the question. I don't want to destroy the question's chance of being answer, and of course, I don't want to bump my edit reject count.

P.S: It's moments like these that make us wish we could retract edits.

Comment: Your edit is already approved, by the way...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Right, thanks! I edited my question to reflect that _that's_ what concerns me. If the information was important, removing it is a problem.

Comment: I don't see an image in the original post...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Exactly! Wow, my edited post and his original post look more different all the time. :|

Comment: I don't know. From where I'm sitting, you simply added some image to the post for some reason...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Now that I **couldn't** have done on accident. I'm almost positive that when I set out to edit the question, it had the link for his image inside his code block because he forgot to close it out with backticks.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you started editing on the original post, then while still in the grace period the OP edited so it doesn't appear as a revision, then you submitted your edit which was relative to the original before the grace-period change. That's my Sherlock moment. Guess only a moderator could clear the fog on the mystery

Comment: @Tomerikoo Wow thank you so much! I had no idea there was a grace period!

Comment: See the last section of [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/571958)

Comment: @Tomerikoo The sequence of events which you describe sounds plausible. If that's what happened, then, as far as I'm aware, only a developer/SE system admin could clear that up, as *no record* is kept in the database of versions which are replaced by an edit during the grace period. There probably are system level logs which record that there was a replacement, but, if so, actually seeing the timing on that would require digging through the log files (i.e. requiring a developer (maybe) or a SE system admin).

Comment: @Makyen THANKS! That won't be necessary, I'm glad I got a mod's response at all.

Comment: Tomerikoo's theory is indeed _very_ plausible. I'm 99% sure that that's what happened because this very thing has happened to me a few times in the past.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yeah, thanks! That's my only reservation; I'm surprised this issue isn't more common.

Comment: I think there is something called Roll back which might help in case like that;